# Multiple values for a model property inside my view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This has me completely stumped so I figured I would ask around and see if there is a solution to this!

I have a ticketing system that I am currently working on and one of the fields is "Primary Contact" -- Code below;

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.Label("Client Contact:")
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrimaryContact, new { placeholder = "Primary contact for this ticket." })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryContact)
    </td>
</tr>
```

I had a user request a feature; the ability to have say a "+" button where they can click and it adds another field (I will accomplish this through javascript.) However, I need the fields that are created by the javascript to be bound to Model.PrimaryContact.. So essentially when the user adds another textbox for another contact it will then make the value of "Model.PrimaryContact" say something like the following:

```
Billy Joe 918-555-5556,Bobby Jane 876-222-3334
```

Then when this gets posted to the controller I can simply insert that into the database.

I am not too sure how this would be accomplished however I believe I'll need some sort of custom model binder that is comma delimited?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "model.PrimaryContacts" to the list of strings `List<string>` and render:

```
    <input type="text" id="PrimaryContacts[0]" name="PrimaryContacts[0]" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="PrimaryContacts[1]" name="PrimaryContacts[1]" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="PrimaryContacts[2]" name="PrimaryContacts[2]" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="PrimaryContacts[3]" name="PrimaryContacts[3]" value="" />
```

It's *important that **"name" attribute is same** on each field* (id doesn't matter), and they will automatically bind into array or collection.

**Update:**

if we assume that PrimaryContact is object with FirstName, LastName and PhoneNumber properties, then we would need to render following markup on the page:

```
    <!-- 1st person -->
    <input type="text" id="[0].FirstName" name="[0].FirstName" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="[0].LastName" name="[0].LastName" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="[0].PhoneNumber" name="[0].PhoneNumber" value="" />
    <!-- 2nd person -->
    <input type="text" id="[1].FirstName" name="[1].FirstName" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="[1].LastName" name="[1].LastName" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="[1].PhoneNumber" name="[1].PhoneNumber" value="" />
```

Above would bind to `List<PrimaryContact>` objects.

**Update 2:**

Last but not least, to bind to the `Dictionary<string, PrimaryContact>` you do this:

```
<!-- 1st person -->
<input type="hidden" id="[0].Key" name="[0].Key" value="1stPersonKey" />
<input type="text" id="[0].FirstName" name="[0].Value.FirstName" value="" />
<input type="text" id="[0].LastName" name="[0].Value.LastName" value="" />
<input type="text" id="[0].PhoneNumber" name="[0].Value.PhoneNumber" value="" />
<!-- 2nd person -->
<input type="hidden" id="[1].Key" name="[1].Key" value="2ndPersonKey" />
<input type="text" id="[1].FirstName" name="[1].Value.FirstName" value="" />
<input type="text" id="[1].LastName" name="[1].Value.LastName" value="" />
<input type="text" id="[1].PhoneNumber" name="[1].Value.PhoneNumber" value="" />
```

Hope this helps a bit

Comment: I assume at that point I would need to iterate through that collection inside my controller to comma separate each value value1,value2,value3, etc and then insert that comma separated list into Model.PrimaryContact?

Comment: You can even bind automatically to the List<PrimaryContact> assuming that you have FirstName, LastName and PhoneNumber as separate properties, but you did not mention it in the question. In any case you don't need custom ModelBinder.

Comment: Cool.. I like this approach as well, it seems easier then implementing knockout for one feature however Knockout is quite appealing to me as this ticketing system will require a more and more sophisticated user interface as it is developed further.

Comment: This helps quite a bit, it is actually quite interesting as I didn't know you could declare the position of the list object such as [1].FirstName etc. This would be a simple solution to what I need to do over using Knockout JS. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... maybe I missed type="text" on fields, but approach works. And I will add indexes on 1st example, although for binder they are not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a time ago used this approach:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Now Im using this:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/

Hope this stuff will help=)

Comment: I think that this will completely solve my entire issue.. I have looked into Knockout before but it has been a while. Let me try to sum this up to make sure I understand correctly. Basically you serialize your model to a JSON object, do all your data binding and then pass the serialized Knockout JSON object to your controller for saving into the database instead of the actual default ModelBinder?

Comment: If what I said above is the case then we are golden and this is a solid solution!

Comment: You pass your model as a json and it actualy binds using your model binder=) Default model binder is capable of binding json. So you will get all model validation stuff on server. On clientside you can do validate your model by own rules if you need clienside validation.

Comment: Oh my... Why do I not use Knockout for everything? >.< It sounds awesome and super versatile! Are there any pitfalls in using it for almost every view that requires a sophisticated UI?